# Doesn't show the prompt with Select Account

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

We use Azure AD B2C tenant and the custom policy.
In the custom policy, we prepare 2 ways for sign-in.

1. Sign-in with the username and password that registered in AD B2C tenant
2. Sign-in with AAD account

[the image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUKz.png)

In sign-in with AAD account, doesn't show the prompt with Select Account,
and executes SSO with some kind of account.
But which is not the account the user want to sign-in.

How to show the promot with Select Account?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDaNq.png)

My code is below
(masking sensitive parameter)

```
IPublicClientApplication ClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(
    new PublicClientApplicationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "<Client ID>",
        TicketContainer = KerberosTicketContainer.AccessToken,
    })
    .WithB2CAuthority($"https://{ TenantName }.b2clogin.com/tfp/{ TenantName }/{ CustomPolicySignUpSignIn }")
    .WithRedirectUri($"https://{ TenantName }.b2clogin.com/oauth2/nativeclient")
    .Build();

return await ClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(new string[] { $"https://{ TenantName }.onmicrosoft.com/<ID>/XXX.fullaccess" })
    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)
    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Best regards,

Comment: Hi @Akihiros, did you find a solution to this problem yet? I have a similar one where the prompt automatically logs in with a guest account of the AD instead showing a choice. I'm not sure if `Prompt.ForceLogin` would be a solution with the downside, that the user would have to enter the credentials every time.